# Issue with OnCollisionEnter2D - No error messages but no result

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, collision

first time posting here so apologies if I get anything wrong. I've written a chunk of code meant to check if the attached object is touching another object with the tag "hazard". If it is then the value of the float "hp" will be reduced by 1. No error messages are present when I run my game but when I run my game and touch an object tagged "hazard" with my player character hp isn't effected - I know this because I successfully implemented a health bar which doesn't change at all when I touch an object with the tag.

Below is the code I have written to detect the collision and reduce the value of hp.

```
void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D col)
    {
        if (col.gameObject.tag =="hazard")
        {
          hp = hp - 1;
        }
    }
```

Both the player character object and hazard objects have 2D Collider components attached.

Upon request the code for the health has been added below:

This code sets the initial value of "hp" and declares the game objects that I later use to represent the remaining health of the player.

```
float hp = 10;
   public GameObject phealth1;
   public GameObject phealth2;
   public GameObject phealth3;
   public GameObject phealth4;
   public GameObject phealth5;
   public GameObject phealth6;
   public GameObject phealth7;
   public GameObject phealth8;
   public GameObject phealth9;
   public GameObject phealth10;
```

This code prevents "hp" from going above or below the maximum and minimum values as well as updating the health bar based on the value of "hp".

```
 void Update()
{
    
    if (hp > 10)
        hp = 10;

    if (hp < 0)
        hp = 0;

    switch (hp) {
        case 10:
            phealth1.gameObject.SetActive(true);
            phealth2.gameObject.SetActive(true);
            phealth3.gameObject.SetActive(true);
            phealth4.gameObject.SetActive(true);
            phealth5.gameObject.SetActive(true);
            phealth6.gameObject.SetActive(true);
            phealth7.gameObject.SetActive(true);
            phealth8.gameObject.SetActive(true);
            phealth9.gameObject.SetActive(true);
            phealth10.gameObject.SetActive(true);
            break;
        case 9:
            phealth1.gameObject.SetActive(true);
            phealth2.gameObject.SetActive(true);
            phealth3.gameObject.SetActive(true);
            phealth4.gameObject.SetActive(true);
            phealth5.gameObject.SetActive(true);
            phealth6.gameObject.SetActive(true);
            phealth7.gameObject.SetActive(true);
            phealth8.gameObject.SetActive(true);
            phealth9.gameObject.SetActive(true);
            phealth10.gameObject.SetActive(false);
            break;
        case 8:
            phealth1.gameObject.SetActive(true);
            phealth2.gameObject.SetActive(true);
            phealth3.gameObject.SetActive(true);
            phealth4.gameObject.SetActive(true);
            phealth5.gameObject.SetActive(true);
            phealth6.gameObject.SetActive(true);
            phealth7.gameObject.SetActive(true);
            phealth8.gameObject.SetActive(true);
            phealth9.gameObject.SetActive(false);
            phealth10.gameObject.SetActive(false);
            break;
        case 7:
            phealth1.gameObject.SetActive(true);
            phealth2.gameObject.SetActive(true);
            phealth3.gameObject.SetActive(true);
            phealth4.gameObject.SetActive(true);
            phealth5.gameObject.SetActive(true);
            phealth6.gameObject.SetActive(true);
            phealth7.gameObject.SetActive(true);
            phealth8.gameObject.SetActive(false);
            phealth9.gameObject.SetActive(false);
            phealth10.gameObject.SetActive(false);
            break;
        case 6:
            phealth1.gameObject.SetActive(true);
            phealth2.gameObject.SetActive(true);
            phealth3.gameObject.SetActive(true);
            phealth4.gameObject.SetActive(true);
            phealth5.gameObject.SetActive(true);
            phealth6.gameObject.SetActive(true);
            phealth7.gameObject.SetActive(false);
            phealth8.gameObject.SetActive(false);
            phealth9.gameObject.SetActive(false);
            phealth10.gameObject.SetActive(false);
            break;
        case 5:
            phealth1.gameObject.SetActive(true);
            phealth2.gameObject.SetActive(true);
            phealth3.gameObject.SetActive(true);
            phealth4.gameObject.SetActive(true);
            phealth5.gameObject.SetActive(true);
            phealth6.gameObject.SetActive(false);
            phealth7.gameObject.SetActive(false);
            phealth8.gameObject.SetActive(false);
            phealth9.gameObject.SetActive(false);
            phealth10.gameObject.SetActive(false);
            break;
        case 4:
            phealth1.gameObject.SetActive(true);
            phealth2.gameObject.SetActive(true);
            phealth3.gameObject.SetActive(true);
            phealth4.gameObject.SetActive(true);
            phealth5.gameObject.SetActive(false);
            phealth6.gameObject.SetActive(false);
            phealth7.gameObject.SetActive(false);
            phealth8.gameObject.SetActive(false);
            phealth9.gameObject.SetActive(false);
            phealth10.gameObject.SetActive(false);
            break;
        case 3:
            phealth1.gameObject.SetActive(true);
            phealth2.gameObject.SetActive(true);
            phealth3.gameObject.SetActive(true);
            phealth4.gameObject.SetActive(false);
            phealth5.gameObject.SetActive(false);
            phealth6.gameObject.SetActive(false);
            phealth7.gameObject.SetActive(false);
            phealth8.gameObject.SetActive(false);
            phealth9.gameObject.SetActive(false);
            phealth10.gameObject.SetActive(false);
            break;
        case 2:
            phealth1.gameObject.SetActive(true);
            phealth2.gameObject.SetActive(true);
            phealth3.gameObject.SetActive(false);
            phealth4.gameObject.SetActive(false);
            phealth5.gameObject.SetActive(false);
            phealth6.gameObject.SetActive(false);
            phealth7.gameObject.SetActive(false);
            phealth8.gameObject.SetActive(false);
            phealth9.gameObject.SetActive(false);
            phealth10.gameObject.SetActive(false);
            break;
        case 1:
            phealth1.gameObject.SetActive(true);
            phealth2.gameObject.SetActive(false);
            phealth3.gameObject.SetActive(false);
            phealth4.gameObject.SetActive(false);
            phealth5.gameObject.SetActive(false);
            phealth6.gameObject.SetActive(false);
            phealth7.gameObject.SetActive(false);
            phealth8.gameObject.SetActive(false);
            phealth9.gameObject.SetActive(false);
            phealth10.gameObject.SetActive(false);
            break;
        case 0:
            phealth1.gameObject.SetActive(false);
            phealth2.gameObject.SetActive(false);
            phealth3.gameObject.SetActive(false);
            phealth4.gameObject.SetActive(false);
            phealth5.gameObject.SetActive(false);
            phealth6.gameObject.SetActive(false);
            phealth7.gameObject.SetActive(false);
            phealth8.gameObject.SetActive(false);
            phealth9.gameObject.SetActive(false);
            phealth10.gameObject.SetActive(false);
            break;
    }

}
```

Below is the entire script.

```
    using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Health : MonoBehaviour
{
   float hp = 10;
   public GameObject phealth1;
   public GameObject phealth2;
   public GameObject phealth3;
   public GameObject phealth4;
   public GameObject phealth5;
   public GameObject phealth6;
   public GameObject phealth7;
   public GameObject phealth8;
   public GameObject phealth9;
   public GameObject phealth10;
   
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        
    }

    void dmg(int x)
    {
        hp = hp - x;
    }

    void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D col)
    {
        if (col.gameObject.tag == "hazard")
            dmg(1);
            Debug.Log("Contact made");
            Debug.Log(hp);
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {

        if (hp > 10)
            hp = 10;

        if (hp < 0)
            hp = 0;

        switch (hp) {
            case 10:
                phealth1.gameObject.SetActive(true);
                phealth2.gameObject.SetActive(true);
                phealth3.gameObject.SetActive(true);
                phealth4.gameObject.SetActive(true);
                phealth5.gameObject.SetActive(true);
                phealth6.gameObject.SetActive(true);
                phealth7.gameObject.SetActive(true);
                phealth8.gameObject.SetActive(true);
                phealth9.gameObject.SetActive(true);
                phealth10.gameObject.SetActive(true);
                break;
            case 9:
                phealth1.gameObject.SetActive(true);
                phealth2.gameObject.SetActive(true);
                phealth3.gameObject.SetActive(true);
                phealth4.gameObject.SetActive(true);
                phealth5.gameObject.SetActive(true);
                phealth6.gameObject.SetActive(true);
                phealth7.gameObject.SetActive(true);
                phealth8.gameObject.SetActive(true);
                phealth9.gameObject.SetActive(true);
                phealth10.gameObject.SetActive(false);
                break;
            case 8:
                phealth1.gameObject.SetActive(true);
                phealth2.gameObject.SetActive(true);
                phealth3.gameObject.SetActive(true);
                phealth4.gameObject.SetActive(true);
                phealth5.gameObject.SetActive(true);
                phealth6.gameObject.SetActive(true);
                phealth7.gameObject.SetActive(true);
                phealth8.gameObject.SetActive(true);
                phealth9.gameObject.SetActive(false);
                phealth10.gameObject.SetActive(false);
                break;
            case 7:
                phealth1.gameObject.SetActive(true);
                phealth2.gameObject.SetActive(true);
                phealth3.gameObject.SetActive(true);
                phealth4.gameObject.SetActive(true);
                phealth5.gameObject.SetActive(true);
                phealth6.gameObject.SetActive(true);
                phealth7.gameObject.SetActive(true);
                phealth8.gameObject.SetActive(false);
                phealth9.gameObject.SetActive(false);
                phealth10.gameObject.SetActive(false);
                break;
            case 6:
                phealth1.gameObject.SetActive(true);
                phealth2.gameObject.SetActive(true);
                phealth3.gameObject.SetActive(true);
                phealth4.gameObject.SetActive(true);
                phealth5.gameObject.SetActive(true);
                phealth6.gameObject.SetActive(true);
                phealth7.gameObject.SetActive(false);
                phealth8.gameObject.SetActive(false);
                phealth9.gameObject.SetActive(false);
                phealth10.gameObject.SetActive(false);
                break;
            case 5:
                phealth1.gameObject.SetActive(true);
                phealth2.gameObject.SetActive(true);
                phealth3.gameObject.SetActive(true);
                phealth4.gameObject.SetActive(true);
                phealth5.gameObject.SetActive(true);
                phealth6.gameObject.SetActive(false);
                phealth7.gameObject.SetActive(false);
                phealth8.gameObject.SetActive(false);
                phealth9.gameObject.SetActive(false);
                phealth10.gameObject.SetActive(false);
                break;
            case 4:
                phealth1.gameObject.SetActive(true);
                phealth2.gameObject.SetActive(true);
                phealth3.gameObject.SetActive(true);
                phealth4.gameObject.SetActive(true);
                phealth5.gameObject.SetActive(false);
                phealth6.gameObject.SetActive(false);
                phealth7.gameObject.SetActive(false);
                phealth8.gameObject.SetActive(false);
                phealth9.gameObject.SetActive(false);
                phealth10.gameObject.SetActive(false);
                break;
            case 3:
                phealth1.gameObject.SetActive(true);
                phealth2.gameObject.SetActive(true);
                phealth3.gameObject.SetActive(true);
                phealth4.gameObject.SetActive(false);
                phealth5.gameObject.SetActive(false);
                phealth6.gameObject.SetActive(false);
                phealth7.gameObject.SetActive(false);
                phealth8.gameObject.SetActive(false);
                phealth9.gameObject.SetActive(false);
                phealth10.gameObject.SetActive(false);
                break;
            case 2:
                phealth1.gameObject.SetActive(true);
                phealth2.gameObject.SetActive(true);
                phealth3.gameObject.SetActive(false);
                phealth4.gameObject.SetActive(false);
                phealth5.gameObject.SetActive(false);
                phealth6.gameObject.SetActive(false);
                phealth7.gameObject.SetActive(false);
                phealth8.gameObject.SetActive(false);
                phealth9.gameObject.SetActive(false);
                phealth10.gameObject.SetActive(false);
                break;
            case 1:
                phealth1.gameObject.SetActive(true);
                phealth2.gameObject.SetActive(false);
                phealth3.gameObject.SetActive(false);
                phealth4.gameObject.SetActive(false);
                phealth5.gameObject.SetActive(false);
                phealth6.gameObject.SetActive(false);
                phealth7.gameObject.SetActive(false);
                phealth8.gameObject.SetActive(false);
                phealth9.gameObject.SetActive(false);
                phealth10.gameObject.SetActive(false);
                break;
            case 0:
                phealth1.gameObject.SetActive(false);
                phealth2.gameObject.SetActive(false);
                phealth3.gameObject.SetActive(false);
                phealth4.gameObject.SetActive(false);
                phealth5.gameObject.SetActive(false);
                phealth6.gameObject.SetActive(false);
                phealth7.gameObject.SetActive(false);
                phealth8.gameObject.SetActive(false);
                phealth9.gameObject.SetActive(false);
                phealth10.gameObject.SetActive(false);
                break;
        }

    }
    
    
}
```

Comment: Does one of the objects have a rigidbody2d component?  From reference: `Note: Trigger events are only sent if one of the Colliders also has a Rigidbody2D attached.`

Comment: Yes, the player character has a rigidbody2d component, since I used it to implement movement.

Comment: If hijinxbassist’s suggestion doesn’t solve it: Try putting a debug message inside OnCollisionEnter2D and see if it prints to the console when inside or outside of the if clause. If it prints outside but not inside when hitting an object, you know it’s the tag check that’s the problem. If it doesn’t print at all you know the collision isn’t registering. 
If you haven’t already, try reducing hp in a similar way somewhere it’ll definitely be called and make sure your health bar is updating correctly. Try anything you can think of to narrow down the potential causes.

Comment: I added a debug message:

```
void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D col)
    {
        if (col.gameObject.tag =="hazard")
        {
          dmg(1);
          Debug.Log("Contact made");
        }
    }
```
It says the collision detection is working, but hp isnt being decreased

Comment: Thanks for that idea - I added another debug.log to check the value of hp and it's going down but between my health bar tests and implementing the collision check my health bar has stopped working. I'll have a look through my code and the inspector to see if I can figure out where I've gone wrong

Comment: I re-added my test code where I pressed "J" to reduce HP by 1 - when I reduce health this way my health bar works as intended. It's only when HP is reduced by the collision check that the health bar doesn't change to reflect this, any idea why this might be? I implemented the health bar by using cases where gameobjects representing health disappear with a case for each value of hp between 0 and 10.

switch (hp) {
           case 10:
               phealth1.gameObject.SetActive(true);
               phealth2.gameObject.SetActive(true);
etc.
Any idea why this may be the case?

Comment: Upon further testing it appears that if I reduce my player character's health to 0 by using the collision check then the health bar will immediately be set to how it should be when hp = 0. So the issue is displaying health correctly for cases 1 to 10

Comment: Please include the health code in your question.

Comment: I have added the rest of the code in my health script - hope this helps.

Comment: Are both code snippets from the same class/file? If not my guess would be that the hp variable used in OnCollisionEnter() is not actually the same variable as used in the health bar script.

Comment: I'm fairly certain that it is using the same hp variable since it eventually does work, just only the final 0 case. I'll update the post with the whole uninterrupted script like I should have done in the first place, maybe seeing the whole thing as a single entity will help? The only other class in my project I am aware of is a separate script used for the movement of the player.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect something is wrong in the scene.

1. Check that there is only one of this script in the scene.

> In the `Hierarchy Tab` type in the search bar `t:MyComponentName`.  Multiple copies using the same phealth objects could cause the issue you are experiencing.

2. Double check your `phealth{n}` gameObjects that are assigned in the inspector.

Here is a cleaned up version of your code.  Tested and confirmed working.

```
using UnityEngine;

public class Health : MonoBehaviour
{
    public int health;
    public int maxHealth;
    public GameObject[] healthObjs;

    private void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D collision)
    {
        if (collision.gameObject.CompareTag("hazard"))
        {
            AddHealth(-1);
        }
    }

    private void AddHealth(int amount)
    {
        health = Mathf.Max(0, Mathf.Min(maxHealth, health + amount));

        UpdateDisplayedHealth();
    }
    private void UpdateDisplayedHealth()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < healthObjs.Length; i++)
        {
            healthObjs[i].SetActive(i + 1 <= health);
        }
    }
}
```

1. Removed the switch case replacing it with a for loop which makes the code much more compact.
2. Updated the damage function to handle the min/max health value and to update the displayed health.
3. Removed Update completely.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help! It turns out I had accidently added the script to another object - once I removed it everything worked as intended.